# SQL server CPU 100% - Turn on Optimize for Adhoc Workload

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Experiencing high CPU the more connections there are, no blocking or long running queries on the server.

Highest wait types are:
SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD & CX_PACKET

Cache Usage %:

```
UsrTab   0.01
Default  0.01
Rule     0.04
Trigger  0.06
Prepared 0.64
Proc     0.7
View     2.05
Adhoc    95.65
```

Adhoc queries are excessive and have seemed to increase since use of ORM functionality has increased.

I would like to turn on  Optimize for Adhoc Workload but want to know the pitfalls, also what are the implications of turning this on in a production environment?

Will enabling this option help reduce CPU load?

Comment: What happened when you enabled it in a lower environment and ran a load test?  Random people with no insight into your application are likely in a poor position to guess at what the impact of changing a parameter would be for your application.  Based on the minimal information you've provided, it sounds reasonable but sounding reasonable to someone on the internet realistically only means that it makes sense to do it in dev and test it out not that you should run out and change the production system.

Comment: Tested it in a couple of non production environments and cant see any noticeable impact but then again its not production so has fraction of the users.

Comment: Can you run a load test in one of those lower environments?  Obviously, if you're looking for an impact in an environment where there is no load and CPU never goes over 1%, no parameter change is going to do anything detectable.  If you get the QA department to spin up 5, 50, 500, or 5000 simultaneous virtual users, though, you'll probably see some impact.

Comment: haha QA department :).. I wish ..i could run some scripted SQL load tests but nothing will be close to the random requests made by end users/ virtual users

Comment: Since `optimize for adhoc workload` affects only storing / reuse of plans, it most likely isn't going to help you. Have you looked at plan cache for the queries using most worker time? There could be something easy to spot from there like huge sorts, UDFs etc.

Comment: Check the power plan - should be high performance (as opposed to the default of balanced).

Comment: @Kin power plan is set to high performance

Comment: @JamesZ I thought excessive adhoc queries impacted CPU though? So surely enabling this setting will help?

Comment: You'll need to have a plan to run a query -- so it's going to be created anyway. `Optimize for adhoc workloads` just stores it after it's needed twice -- so you'll save memory if you only run same queries once, but probably isn't going to solve CPU issues.

Comment: Surely the more memory load the more CPU load especially if the CPU can't actually use anything in the memory and is constantly clearing it out.

Comment: pah just read it might increase CPU overhead as the plan is recompiled twice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn on "Optimize for Adhoc Workloads" with a high confidence.

The only potential effect this has, is when a plan is compiled the second time, it takes a few microseconds longer. This is because the first time a plan is cached, it only records the stub.

After that, the full plan is already cached, and you'll see the benefits.

---

Aside: if you're seeing high CPU as a result of a new OR/M, I'd look at something called implicit conversion.

What happens is that on string data types (`CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, `NCHAR`, `NVARCHAR`), you might be seeing Unicode vs ASCII conversions between the database and your application code.

The best way to look for this is to make sure your ORM matches the string data types correctly. If it's `VARCHAR` in the database, make sure the ORM doesn't submit parameters as `NVARCHAR`.

*More reading here: [Convert Implicit and the related performance issues with SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1734/convert-implicit-and-the-related-performance-issues-with-sql-server/).*

Comment: Thanks will looks into the conversion types i think in most cases the Devs match them. I did read that ORMs can also have a tendacy to increase adhoc requests as well,  and the servers SQL compilations per batch requests is a round 40% not ideal , this figure should be closer to 10%. So nothing seems to be getting reused from cache. Queries seem to be very quick with no blocking, just high CPU

Comment: Yeah, that's ORMs for you. You could also try adding Forced Parameterization, but that you'll have to test solidly to see if it helps. It might, it might not. Try get the developers to use stored procedures and see how compilations drop!

Comment: Yep bit skeptical about turning on forced Parameterizationj ust yet...looking for a quickish fix hence adhoc workload feature  haha, yep sprocs are the way to go but ORMs are easier for the devs :(

Comment: I've added both with little effect.  I would have thought Forced Parameterization would have helped here but still getting loads of adhoc queries in cache 100,000 + in the space of 30mins

Comment: Yeah, I have a customer with that problem too, for the same reason. You can clear them out using a scheduled process in the SQL Agent.