# Does "Table Valued Function" force the plan to get into cache?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, optimization, functions, plan-cache

`sp_executesql` and stored procedures force the plan generated from t-sql to get put into the cache, does this behaviour is shared with table value function or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does this behaviour is shared with table value function or not?

the short answer is: 
It is not, because if you check [what execution plans you have in the cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-cached-plans-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) these are the objects you can find there:

cacheobjtype    nvarchar(34)    Type of object in the cache. 
The value can be one of the following:

1. Compiled Plan
2. Compiled Plan Stub
3. Parse Tree
4. Extended Proc
5. CLR Compiled Func
6. CLR Compiled Proc

You may be looking to consider:

[Plan cache and optimizing for adhoc workloads](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/plan-cache-and-optimizing-for-adhoc-workloads/)

check what your plan cache is made up of:

```
SELECT objtype AS [CacheType],
    COUNT_BIG(*) AS [Total Plans],
    SUM(CAST(size_in_bytes AS DECIMAL(18, 2))) / 1024 / 1024 AS [Total MBs],
    AVG(usecounts) AS [Avg Use Count],
    SUM(CAST((CASE WHEN usecounts = 1 THEN size_in_bytes
        ELSE 0
        END) AS DECIMAL(18, 2))) / 1024 / 1024 AS [Total MBs – USE Count 1],
    SUM(CASE WHEN usecounts = 1 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
        END) AS [Total Plans – USE Count 1]
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans
GROUP BY objtype
ORDER BY [Total MBs – USE Count 1] DESC
GO
```

[image]

[Minimize plan cache bloat with the optimize for ad hoc workloads configuration option](https://logicalread.com/sql-server-minimize-single-use-plans-tl01/#.Xrh_J2hKiXI)

> SQL Server 2008 introduced the ‘[optimize for ad-hoc workloads](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/155232/22336)’
>   configuration option which, when enabled, causes SQL Server to create
>   a plan stub instead of a full plan the first time a statement is
>   executed. If the plan is used a second time, then SQL Server will
>   store the full plan. This option was introduced to help minimize the
>   performance impact of plan cache bloat.

and another thing I would like to mention is..

High compiles ([not recompiles](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/09/what-to-do-if-sp_blitzfirst-warns-about-high-compilations/)):

[High Compiles and Multi-Statement Table Valued Functions](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/01/high-compiles-multi-statement-table-valued-functions/)

Comment: so in this case it's better to convert all my Table valued function into stored procedures , what do you think ?

Comment: not necessarily, it depends really on what improvement you want\need\envision to achieve. if you are experiencing bad performance in some or on a function in specific, ask another question specifically on that. make sure you add the execution plan and a link to this question too.